# how to use gtts repeatedly?

Tags: python, gtts

when i call my function once i have no errors but if i call it **repeatedly** i will have the following error :

> Exception has occurred: PermissionError [Errno 13] Permission denied:
>   'tolkback.mp3'

```
from gtts import gTTS
import pyglet
from playsound import playsound


def TalkBack(case_ans):
    print("in ...................................")
    tts = gTTS(case_ans)

    tts.save('tolkback.mp3')

    print("saving...............................")
    playsound('tolkback.mp3')
    print("saying................................")


TalkBack("my bad end 1")
TalkBack("go go end 2")
TalkBack("find me my self end 3")
TalkBack("games maker end 4")
TalkBack("say my name end 5")
```

the program should talk back the text

Comment: code works correctly for me on Linux Mint / Python 3.7

Comment: hmmmmmmmm i am working on windows10 Python 3.7 , but still repeatedly i have a problem , any way thank you for trying

Comment: you could check `Errno 13` in Google. Maybe there is solution for this. Or maybe you would have to add code which delete this file after playing. Or maybe you will have to create random name for every execution.

Comment: thank you for the tip i made something that works , i will add as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the solution that i made  >> with the Gide of my friend [furas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1832058/furas)

```
from playsound import playsound
import webSearch
import os
import random

def name_generator():
    ran = random.randint(1,5000)
    ran = str(ran)
    return ran


def TalkBack(case_ans):
    print("in ...................................")
    tts = gTTS(case_ans)
    new_name = name_generator()
    new_name= new_name+".mp3"
    tts.save(new_name)

    print("saving...............................")
    playsound(new_name)
    print("saying................................")
    try:
        os.remove(new_name) 
    except:
        print("i cant")



TalkBack("my bad end 1")
TalkBack("go go end 2")
TalkBack("find me my self end 3")
TalkBack("games maker end 4")
TalkBack("say my name end 5")
```

generating a new .mp3 file with a random name and deleting it after using it

Comment: by the way: Python has standard module which can create random filename - `import tempfile` and `name = tempfile.mktemp(suffix='.mp3', dir='.')`